# How do I delete a feeding band from my Pandora station?

Tags: pandora

So I have searched this question may times and I still cannot find an answer. What I have seen tells me to go to station details and then swipe from right to left across any band I do not want feeding. This motion is supposed to unveil a button that says remove but so far the screen has not changed. Is there something else I need to do? I'm really quite tired of hearing "Soul Sisters" on my *Disturbed* radio station.

Comment: Are you referring to the native app or the web app?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and wrote to Pandora.  Their response was:  "It sounds like you need to check the bookmark that you use to access Pandora.

It should ONLY be:  http://pandora.com

If there is anything added onto it (ie:  http://pandora.com#//genres/top) then erase that.  That is most likely the problem.

Hope this helps!!